# Update QProgressBar from QFutureWatcher

Tags: qt, qthread

I am trying to update QProgressBar from QFutureWatcher. But the progress bar is not updated. Signals do not reach the progress bar. Here is my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent)
   , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto* progress = ui->progressBar;
    QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, progress, &QProgressBar::reset);
    QObject::connect(ui->stopBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, &futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::cancel);
    QObject::connect(&futureWatcher,  &QFutureWatcher<void>::progressRangeChanged, progress, &QProgressBar::setRange);
    QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::progressValueChanged,  progress, &QProgressBar::setValue);
}

std::function<void(int&)> spin = [](int& iter) {
    const int work = 1000 * 1000 * 40;
    volatile int v = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < work; ++j)
    ++v;

    qDebug() << "iteration " << iter << " in thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
};

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    for (int i =0; i < 200; i++)
        m_list.push_back(i);

    qDebug() << QString("Progressing using %1 thread(s)...").arg(QThread::idealThreadCount());

    m_fututre = QtConcurrent::map(m_list, spin);
    futureWatcher.setFuture(m_fututre);
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: are the connections correctly established? What will it print if you do `qDebug() << QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::progressValueChanged,  progress, &QProgressBar::setValue);` when connecting?

Comment: Btw. where is your `futureWatcher` delaration and definition? Is it a global variable? Or what is its lifetime? Are you sure you did not delete it during the run of the future? Then the connections would be disconnected automatically and you would not even notice it.